# C++ programme crashes when compiled

Tags: c++, c++11, codelite

This is my code.After it compiles, the console starts but crashes immediately saying that name.exe has stopped working. warning: extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11. \\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string> //introducing string classes.
struct cia
{
    std::string name;
    std::string code;
    float balance;
};




int main()
{
   using namespace std;

    cia agent[10] =
    {

     agent[0] =
     {    "wallflower",
         "007860",
         300000
     },

     agent[1] =
     {
         "albus",
         "117861",
         310000
     },

     agent[2] =
     {
         "severus",
         "227862",
         600000
     },

     agent[3] =
     {
         "enigma",
         "337862",
         550000
     },


    };

   string head="\n\t\t\t\t\tCIA";
   string username;
   string pass;


   cout<<head;
   cout<<"\n Welcome To The Most Secure network of Justice.";
   cout<<"Username-; ";
   cin>>username;
   getch();


}
```

Comment: programs crash only *after* they have been compiled.  Before they have been compiled they cannot run, so they cannot crash.

Comment: Yes, but after it compiles, it stops immediately. I meant to say that console (cmd) crashes.

Comment: How are you compiling the program? What does your compiler commandline look like? What compiler are you using (and what version)?

Comment: i am using mingw32 compiler, and codelite as an IDE.

Comment: TDM-GCC version 1.1309.0

Comment: I think you goofed up the syntax of what you want to do and ended up trying to initialize your array by using the uninitialized array values. Try removing the `agent[0] = `, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the agents is wrong. You should use something like:

```
    cia agent[4];
     agent[0] =
     {    "wallflower",
         "007860",
         300000
     };

     agent[1] =
     {
         "albus",
         "117861",
         310000
     };

     agent[2] =
     {
         "severus",
         "227862",
         600000
     };

     agent[3] =
     {
         "enigma",
         "337862",
         550000
     };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the struct should be like this:

```
cia agent[10] = {
    {"wallflower", "007860, 300000},
    {"albus", "117861", 310000},
     ... and so on
};
```